# Getting the thread id in Gmail

Tags: javascript, multithreading, email, gmail

I'm looking for a way to figure out how to get the thread id for a particular email on Gmail, just before it is sent OR at the point where the send button is clicked.

Currently, I'm working with Javascript in order to scrape other items off the email and store them in a record which works pretty well for everything except the thread id.

The thread ID can be found after I send the email within the URL:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#inbox/13ddda647539dcca
```

In this case, the thread id (if I'm right - is 13ddda647539dcca.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
var matched = window.location.hash.match(/[A-Za-z0-9]+$/);
if (matched) {
    // Found alphanumeric string at end of hash
}
```

And you can get the value with `matched[0]`.

`window.location.hash` should only grab the "#inbox/13ddda647539dcca" part. Then the regex is to match against any alphanumeric characters at the end of the string. So the fact that "inbox" is separated from the thread id by a "/" is important.

Of course, all of this depends on the reliability of Gmail keeping the URL following the same convention as it currently seems to be.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This would work if I was just getting it off the URL, but I'm trying to get this id before the email is sent - or when the **send** button is clicked. The main purpose is for me to have direct access to this email after its been sent.

Comment: @HappyCry I understand your point, but I"m a little confused. Is this for a **new** email or is for **replying** to a thread? When replying to a thread, it should be available in the URL as you're replying, so my method should work. If it's for a new email, I'm not sure what you want is possible (unless the email has been saved during the compose). It seems that when you compose, the URL has "#compose" at the end. Only **after** you send/save the email, does the URL change to have a thread ID. I don't think an ID is created until you finally send it because the ID is created on the server

Comment: I think you're right. This method is fine for using it in the reply box. Since the ID is created on the server, would you think of any other unique identifier that I can attach with the email on **send**? Thanks for your help, really appreciate it.

Comment: @HappyCry Hmm I can't think of anything. I mean, I don't know the internals of Gmail, but the way things normally work for **new** things, the unique identifier is set after it's created, and it has no identity before. Like I said though, if the email is **saved** during Compose, the URL changes and you can get the thread ID that way. But I'm sure there are a few "unique" things you might be able to pick up about the email before it's sent. I tried to scan through the HTML and I couldn't find anything (like in hidden elements), but it might be a question for the Google team

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is still interested - You can retrieve the thread id after the email is sent by observing the  that appears at the top of the page. This span contains a link which has an attribute named '**param**' which has the thread-id.